# Unable to access some DOM methods in Electron renderer process

Tags: javascript, dom, electron

Let me preface this question with the current setup I have:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1></h1>
        <p>Note One</p>
    </body>
    <script>
        require('./renderer.js')
    </script>
</html>
```

**main.js** *main process*

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

let mainWindow = null

app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow()
    mainWindow.webContents.loadFile('index.html')
})
```

And below is the renderer, where I play around with some basic DOM methods. Some work and others fail:

**renderer.js**

```
document.querySelector('p').remove()
const h2 = document.createElement('h2')
h2.textContent = 'test'
```

Breakdown of `renderer.js`:

The first line works as expected, the first `p` element is returned and removed.

The second line doesn't cause any visible errors but silently fails to create an `h2` element in the DOM, and therefore no text is added on line 3.

I don't understand this behavior, why am I not able to access all the DOM API within the renderer process?

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? `textContent` is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `document.querySelector('p').remove()` works, because `querySelector` returns a single `<p>` element which has a `.remove` method.

The second line `document.createElement('h2')` creates a new `<h2>` element, but apparently you don't *add it to the DOM*, so the GC removes it. Try:

```
const h2 = document.createElement('h2');
h2.textContent = 'Test createElement';
document.body.appendChild(h2);
```

See if that works (hint: It should!).

Comment: Calling it `textContent` as a function was unintended, I edited that part of the question. Thanks for explaining the behavior with appending.